# Cannot reach files (assets) inside assets folder in Laravel

Tags: laravel-6

I am new laravel. Recently I bought new laraval+bootstrap template from online. Now I am trying to serve project via artisan.
The project runs but template dont look as it was. I researched it and found out that it doesn't read css, javascript and other files from assets folder which is nearby public folder. Now i need help to read these files from assets folder.
The app folder structure is as below.
[image]

I slighly modified .htaccess file, but nothing changed

```
<link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/chartist-js/chartist.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
   <!-- Datepicker CSS -->
  <link href="{{ asset('assets/plugins/datepicker/datepicker.min.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

Simply not reads files inside assets folder

Answer (score 0):

These assets should not be within an `assets` folder in the root of your application.

Place assets within the `public` folder.

`asset()` helper links to the `public` directory of your application.

Comment: But i have another project in laravel (another developer wrote it). I just served it locally. And its all assets located in assets folder. But what about that?

Comment: The `assets()` helper may have been overwritten to server these assets from that folder. Check to see if there is a `Helpers.php` within the app folder.

Comment: There is helpers.php in vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php this location, but there is not Helpers.php in project

Comment: It may be in a custom package. One way to find out is to check the `composer.json` files and see if any files are autoloaded

Comment: Either way, putting the `assets` folder in the root of your application is not necessary.

Comment: i know if put all files to public folder it will work. but it is time consuming to change every blade in project. i checked composer.json there is not anything named assets

Comment: You wouldn't need to, adding the `assets` folder directly into the `public` folder should give you the result you need.

Comment: But i am confused. How that projects serve files from that folder?

Comment: `{{ asset('assets/plugins/chartist-js/chartist.min.css') }}` would resolute in `http://example.com/public/assets/plugins/chartist-js/chartist.min.css`. As long as you put the `assets` folder in the `public` folder, it will look for the `assets` folder first.